# meaning of "linger in the shadows"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "linger in the shadows" mean in the interchange below? I heard it in a movie.

I searched but I can't find it.

> A: Why do you linger in the shadows?
>   
> B: I was coming to report to you.

Comment: Barring actual context, it probably means that someone was hiding so as not to be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed. It is an intentional desire for anonymity but often implies a skulking or "devious" intent.  For example, you wouldn't normally say "the mother lingered in the shadows at her daughters dance recital" but might say "the man frequently lingered in the shadows of the auditorium prior to the fire" (or other sinister act.)